# Leaflet: Keep PopUp Open

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I'm trying to create a popup that stays open until I click the x in the top right corner to close it down. What is the best way to do this? My code is below, thanks!

```
      //pop up code
     //create custom icon
      var newicon = L.icon({
        iconUrl: 'logo.png',
      })

      // creating marker
      var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(41.77, -87.6), {
      icon: L.mapbox.marker.icon({
          'marker-color': 'ff8888'
      }),
      icon: newicon,
      draggable: true,
  }).addTo(map);

      // bind popup to marker
      marker.bindPopup("I am a text that will stay open until closed").openPopup();
```

Answer (score 2):

New solution, the old one doesn't seem to work:

```
var new_popup = L.popup({"autoClose": false, "closeOnClick": null});

marker.bindPopup(new_popup);
```

Answer (score 1):

To get poups to open, you need to start by specifying `closePopupOnClick: false` inside `L.map()` so that no popups close by default

```js
L.map("map", {
    // ...
    closePopupOnClick : false,
})
```

Then, for individual popups that you do want to close, you can close them inside `click()`

```js
map.on("popupopen", (e) => {
    // save e.popup to an array or something
});

map.on("click", () => {
    // close the popups you want to by calling map.closePopup(popup);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
var newpopup = L.popup({ closeOnClick: false }).setContent("I am a text that will stay open until closed");

marker.bindPopup(newpopup);
```

Comment: How would I bind this to a marker though? Right now I'm declaring a new object and binding it to the marker, but the popup still closes `var newpopup = L.popup({
        closeOnClick: false
      })
        .setContent("I am a text that will stay open until closed")
        .openOn(map);       marker.bindPopup(newpopup).openPopup()`